# Passing an array into a component in Angular 1.5 through an attribute

Tags: angularjs, arrays, syntax-error, components

I'm trying to pass an array from the parent controller into a child component.

`<plant-select plants="{{head.permittedPlants}}"></plant-select>`

the head.permittedPlants is an array

I get the following error:

"Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{head.permittedPlants}}] starting at [{head.permittedPlants}}]."

can I only pass a string in?

my component looks like this:

```
let plantSelectComponent = {
  bindings:{
  plants:'<'
},
  template:require('./plantSelect.template.html'),
  controller:plantSelectController
}
```

controller of the parent below. The "permittedPlantsResolve" is a resolves from UI-Router:

```
function headerCtrl($scope, $ngRedux, $mdSidenav, $log, permittedPlantsResolve){

  let ctrl = this;


 ctrl.permittedPlants = permittedPlantsResolve;


 ctrl.consoleState = function(){
    console.log($ngRedux.getState());
  }

  ctrl.menuToggle = function(){
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle()
  }

}

export default headerCtrl;
```

if I change the binding to an "@" it passes the string no problem. Are arrays a possibility? do I HAVE to pass a string?

SOLVED: in the controller for the component I was assigning the $attrs.plants on postLink, assigning it onInit fixed the issue!

Comment: He template file that holds the <plant-select> is not a component, just html with a controller attached. Does it need to be a component as well?

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the {{}} in your template you should be fine still using one way binding (<). The reasons @ works is because {{}} is evaluating your head.permittedPlants to a string before passing. If you plan on changing your array in your component, then you need to use the two way binding (=).

Comment: When I do that what gets passed to my component is just a string "head.permittedPlants"

Comment: Can you post your controller as well?

Comment: Are you sure *head* is the name of your controller in your template?

Comment: Yes. Everywhere else in the template I'm using "head" as the controllerAs and it's working fine. 

    <a ng-click="head.menuToggle()">

etc..

Comment: Strange... the only other thing I can think of is your permittedPlantsResolve is not an array...

Comment: console.log(Array.isArray(permittedPlantsResolve)) comes out true. :(

Comment: `<plant-select plants="head.permittedPlants"></plant-select>`
`
`bindings:{
  plants:'='
},`

And this doesn't work? If not, I'm out of guesses, sorry :(

Comment: Hey. I just solved it. I needed to set the value in my plantSelectController onInit, not on postLink like I was doing. Anyway. Thank you for  your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the bindings of plants from < to = and remove the curly braces around the property in the HTML.

Comment: When I do that what gets passed to my component is just a string "head.permittedPlants"

Comment: actually, remove the quotes and leave the curly brace

Comment: @Ladmerc with braces and no quotes, still same issue. Passes string "head.permittedPlants"